# set to list conversion

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, set

Can anyone explain to me why :

```
p = {-1,2,-3}
print(p)
```

will print

```
{2, -3, -1}
```

and when I convert to list

```
pa = list(p)
print(pa)
```

I will get

```
[2, -3, -1]
```

How can I convert p to a list with the same order of items

```
[-1, 2, -3]
```

PS: this happens only when I am using negative items

Comment: sets are not ordered. In a word: you cannot preserve order unless you stored the order ...

Comment: Seemingly-odd things happen around this with small integers because they hash to their own values, so are often (but not always) kept in sorted order. But you should not rely on dictionary or set order.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. I know already that sets are immutable. But I don't have a choice. I am getting a set from a method. I have to convert it to a list (while keeping the same order) in order to feed it to another method. Any help !!

Comment: Sets are are **not immutable**. They are **unordered**. There is no order to keep.

Answer (score 0):

`set` in python are unordered. In case you want to maintain the order of elements, use `collections.OrderedDict.fromkeys()` instead. This will also behave as a `set`. For example:

```
>>> import collections
>>> p = collections.OrderedDict.fromkeys([-1,2,-3])
>>> print(p)
OrderedDict([(-1, None), (2, None), (-3, None)])
>>> p = collections.OrderedDict.fromkeys([-1,2,-3,2]) # <-- 2 repeated twice
>>> print(p)  # <-- Removed duplicated entry of '2', same as set
OrderedDict([(-1, None), (2, None), (-3, None)])
>>> l = list(p)
>>> print(l)  # <-- order is maintained
[-1, 2, -3]
```

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work because fromkeys does not take sets as parameter

Comment: You need to replace the code where your initializing `set` to `collections.OrderedDict.fromkeys()`. Once you have created the set, there is no way you could extract the original order from it.

Comment: I have to find a another way around. But thank you anyway.